# Composer error. [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]

Tags: php, composer-php

Helo,

so i have problem with composer. I have installed xampp(php 7.3.28) and latest composer. when i try to run composer in the command line i gives me an error:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "C:\composer\composer.bat" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:
  @echo OFF:: in case
  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I tried uninstall and reinstall xampp and composer. It did not solved the problem. Please Help me what to do.

I tried to validate my Json code and its valid. I think maybe php version is the problem, but php 7.4.19 was giving me the same.

Comment: Please share more details. How do you "run composer"? Why does it try to load a bat file?

Comment: A batch file is not JSON, that's not unexpected. How do you run composer? Please add details, like commands issues and output received! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Where do you see that parsing exception mentioned in the title?